# Common usage of "namely"

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I got an email today:

> Medical will be sending some people over to give a talk, namely Joe Foo and Bob Bar.

I know the dictionary says *namely* means:

> adverb /ˈnāmlē/ 
>   That is to say; to be specific (used to introduce detailed information or a specific example)
>   - to me there is only one kind of rock, namely, loud rock

But I always thought it means "mainly" from context, e.g., "The students are rioting, namely the engineering students."

What does it mean to you?

Comment: Pretty much that: to specify. As a matter of speech, it allows you to add emphasis by placing the named subject at the end of a sentence. Consider the tone of "the engineering students cause a lot of trouble" against "some students cause a lot of trouble, namely the engineering students."

Comment: I wouldn't consider namely to mean 'mainly'. Perhaps you've mixed up the nasal stops in your understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to remove *namely* from your examples and rephrase the clauses, the new sentences would still be independently accurate:

> *Medical will be sending some people over to give a talk, namely Joe Foo and Bob Bar.*
>
> - Medical will be sending some people over to give a talk.
> - Medical will be sending Joe Foo and Bob Bar over to give a talk.
>
> *The students are rioting, namely the engineering students.*
>
> - The students are rioting.
> - The engineering students are rioting.

*Namely* just offers more information. It is useful when introducing basic ideas followed by an added degree of specificity.  Your intepretation of *namely* to mean *mainly* or *primarily* is probably a corruption of the fact that the specified group is a subset of a larger group which could include any number of other subset groups: literature students, business students, science students, for example. *Namely* is intended to single out just one subset from a larger group.

Answer (score 1):

Namely, here, is used to connect an additional information to the clause. You could also say:

> Medical will be sending some people
>   over to give a talk, 'specifically' Joe
>   Foo and Bob Bar.

Answer (score -1):

Namely gives specificity, particularly when naming the participants in a preceding general clause. It is an element of style used to add colour to a paragraph. The statement can often be reworded to remove "namely", without changing the meaning of the sentence but while losing the stylistic effect, as in the following example.

- Some student representatives disagreed, namely those from engineering and law.
- Student representatives from engineering and law disagreed.

Fowler's Dictionary uses it for specificity in the following quote

> ...credence traditionally had only one main meaning, namely 'belief, trustful acceptance'...